# How do I import tokens in Limesurvey that have special characters with a .csv file with many tokens?

Tags: limesurvey

Trying to import a .csv file in Limesurvey with special characters as å, æ, ø, it does not work at all. I found the characters disappear at the end and I don´t have the right name.

Do you know a solution so these characters don´t disappear?

I suppose I can try to insert them in the Limesurvey one by one, but a general solution to be faster (because I have many contacts) is really apreciated.

Thank you very much in advance!

Jorge

Answer (score 0):

- Solution one : use LibreOffice calc to produce your CSV file, andselect UTF8 when export CSV
- Solution 2, when import : use the good Character set, i can not know your encoding, depend of your language. Try Windows-1250 maybe.